# Connect edge with perpendicular edge

Tags: edges

Is there a way to connect the selected face (white in the image) to the edge in front of it?

[image]

Result should create two vertices in the facing edge and simply merge the selected edge with the newly created edge.

Hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest solution in this case may be using a ***knife tool***. Press <kbd>K</kbd> and snap the knife to the vertices. After pressing the <kbd>LMB</kbd> press <kbd>C</kbd> to make the cut go straight and cut the longer piece horizontally. Repeat the process for the other vertex. Now you can use a *bridge tool* to connect pieces (and then dissolve the unnecessary edge). You may also use a *snapping tool (vertex)* to connect pieces and then *remove doubles*.
[image]

Comment: That's precisely what I needed. Thanks a bunch.